# preg_replace for changing several things

Tags: php, xml, preg-replace

I want to change following xml code (a small part of xml) to html by using `preg_replace()`. I tried xml parse tools, but I have experienced problems at the rest of the xml, so I try to find a solution like `preg_replace()`.

```
<contrib-group>
    <contrib contrib-type="author">
        <name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
            <given-names>John</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1" />
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author">
        <name>
            <surname>Hoper</surname>
            <given-names>Alfred</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff2">2</xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author">
        <name>
            <surname>Bay</surname>
            <given-names>Elisabeth</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff3">3</xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author">
        <name>
            <surname>Back</surname>
            <given-names>James</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff2">2</xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type="author">
        <name>
            <surname>Hampton</surname>
            <given-names>George</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff4">4</xref>
    </contrib>
</contrib-group>
```

The final text should be like:

```
Smith J<sup>1*</sup>, Hoper A<sup>2</sup>, Bay E<sup>3</sup>, Back J<sup>2</sup>, Hampton G<sup>4</sup>
```

I could change some of them by using the following expressions:

```
$data = preg_replace('/<xref(.*?)>(.*?)<\/xref>/i', '<sup>$2</sup>', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/</contrib>.*?<contrib contrib-type="author">/i', ', ', $data);
```

But I could not do all of them.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You will experience a lot more problems with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: use an xml parser (`SimpleXMLElement`) instead